# Show submenu on different div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi please see the following html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sub").on({
     mouseenter: function (event) {
     $(".second.menu").addClass("show");
  }
  });
  $(".no-sub").on({
     mouseenter: function (event) {
     $(".second.menu").removeClass("show");
  }
  });
});
```

```css
.second.menu {
  display:none;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.show {
  display:block !important;
  width:100% !important;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:wheat;
  padding:5px;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  min-width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu first">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="no-sub">Home</li>
    <li class="sub color" >Color List</li>
    <li class="no-sub">Type List</li>
    <li class="no-sub">Type</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="second menu">
  <ul class="nav" id="color">
      <li>Green</li>
      <li>Blue</li>
      <li>Red</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Here everything is working fine. But the problem is that when some one hover the color menu it is showing the submenu. But if they hover and go to any part of the page, submenu is not hiding. How can I do this?  Please help to get the solution on simple way.

Comment: This could be done in all CSS with such a simple setup. But to answer your question, you will need to use the mouseleave event.

Comment: could you please write then css

Comment: You can simply follow https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp to create it using pure css.

Comment: Side-note: it is unreasonably hard to manipulate such events as “mouseenter” and “mouseleave” when the device is controlled via touchscreen (a phone, a tablet, a watch, a fridge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MouseLeave` to exit the second menu

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sub").on({
     mouseenter: function (event) {
     $(".second.menu").addClass("show");
  }
  });
  $(".second.menu").on({
     mouseleave: function (event) {
     $(".second.menu").removeClass("show");
     }
  });
  $(".no-sub").on({
     mouseenter: function (event) {
     $(".second.menu").removeClass("show");
  }
  });
});
```

```css
.second.menu {
  display:none;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.show {
  display:block !important;
  width:100% !important;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:wheat;
  padding:5px;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  min-width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu first">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="no-sub">Home</li>
    <li class="sub color" >Color List</li>
    <li class="no-sub">Type List</li>
    <li class="no-sub">Type</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="second menu">
  <ul class="nav" id="color">
      <li>Green</li>
      <li>Blue</li>
      <li>Red</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: My pleasure. See this link for insiprations [https://1stwebdesigner.com/css-effects/](https://1stwebdesigner.com/css-effects/). Most of the examples are HTML, CSS and JQuery with source code available. I think it will be very useful for your studies.

Answer (score 2):

Just use mouseleave on sub class as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sub").on({
        mouseenter: function (event) {
            $(".second.menu").addClass("show");
        }
    });
    $(".sub").on({
        mouseleave: function (event) {
            $(".second.menu").removeClass("show");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but it has an unintended side effect of hiding the menu when you attempt to hover it, as well. Essentially, never allowing a user to click on any sub-menu links.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach `.mouseleave()` to a new event handler for leaving the submenu itself. Also, try and use `.hide()` and `.show()`

https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub").on({
        mouseenter: function (event) {
            $(".second.menu").show();
        }
    });
    // add this event handler 
    $(".second").on({
        mouseleave: function (event) {
         $(".second.menu").hide();
        }
    });
    $(".no-sub").on({
        mouseenter: function (event) {
            $(".second.menu").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.second.menu{
   display:none;
   margin-top:5px;
 }
 .show{
   display:block !important;
   width:100% !important;
   overflow:hidden;
   background:wheat;
   padding:5px;
 }
 .nav li{
   float: left;
   min-width: 80px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin-right: 1px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: center;
   list-style: none;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="menu first">
     <ul class="nav">
       <li class="no-sub">Home</li>
       <li class="sub color" >Color List</li>
       <li class="no-sub">Type List</li>
       <li class="no-sub">Type</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="second menu">
     <ul class="nav" id="color">
     <li>Green</li>
     <li>Blue</li>
     <li>Red</li>
     </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```