# Div disappears when mouse cursor moves

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I keep the hover Div open when cursor is within Div *show-on-hover*?
Right now it disappear soon as the cursor moves away. I need the "Hover over me!" link to outside the div.

Update:

I'm trying to build a navigation so when visitor hovers over Desserts, its shows a sub menu. Please see code below

```
<table width="66%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="4%" height="265" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="26%" align="left" valign="top"><br> <br>
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size:38px; color:#000; line-height: 30px; letter-spacing:5px;">Navigation</span>
    
    <p style="font-family: Nunito; font-size:15px; color:#485965; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">
     </p>
    <p style="font-family: Nunito; font-size:15px; color:#485965; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;"> </p>
    <p style="font-family: Nunito; font-size:15px; color:#485965; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="font-family: Nunito; font-size:15px; color:#485965; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">
    <span style="font-family: oswald; font-size:20px; color:#aa1b1b; text-transform:uppercase; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing:5px;"></span></p>
    <p style="font-family: Nunito; font-size:15px; color:#485965; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;</p>
    
    
    </td>
    <td width="30%" align="center" valign="top">
      <br>
      
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="">
        <tr>
          <td width="1%"></td>
          <td width="94%"><a target="_blank"  href="" style="font-family: 'arial', sans-serif; font-size:17px; color:#333; text-decoration:none;">Home</a></td>
          <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><a target="_blank" href="" style="font-family: arial; font-size:17px; color:#333; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none; ">Cooking</a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><a target="_blank" href="" style="font-family: arial; font-size:17px; color:#333; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">Receipt</a></td>
          <td>&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td bgcolor="#E5F0FA"><a target="_blank" href="" style="font-family: arial; font-size:17px; color:#333; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">Desserts</a></td>
          <td bgcolor="#E5F0FA">&gt;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><a target="_blank" href="" style="font-family: arial; font-size:17px; color:#333; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">Blog</a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><a target="_blank" href="" style="font-family: arial; font-size:17px; color:#333; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">Downloads</a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><a target="_blank" href="" style="font-family: arial; font-size:17px; color:#333; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration:none;">Contact </a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr> 
  </table>    
    </td>
    <td width="1%" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="39%" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#e5f0fa">
     <!--- SUB NAV---->
    <p>
      <strong>Sub Menu</strong><br><br>      
      Chocolate<br>
      Ice Cream<br>
      Cinnamon-Honey<br>
      Cookies<br>
      Cake
      <br>      
    </p>   
   <!--- /SUB NAV---->  
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: After your edit, it is not likely that the previous CSS will work with this structure. The [adjacent sibling combinator (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) requires two elements to be adjacent siblings, which is not the case in the updated HTML. You might consider a [different structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308995/924299) or [JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569436/show-submenu-on-different-div-on-hover).

Answer (score 1):

One method is to hide `.show-on-hover` on load.
Then you can show it whenever `.hoverable` or `.show-on-hover` is hovered.

I also set `.hoverable` to `display:block` and changed the `<ul>` margins to padding, in order to eliminate the gap in hover areas between `.hoverable` and `.show-on-hover`.

```css
.show-on-hover {
  display: none;
}

.hoverable {
  display: block;
}

.show-on-hover ul {
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:1em;
}

.hoverable:hover+.show-on-hover,
.show-on-hover:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="hoverable">Hover over me!</a>
<div class="show-on-hover">
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Another method is to put `.hoverable` inside `.show-on-hover`.
But this changes the structure of your HTML, which might be undesirable.

```css
.show-on-hover ul {
  display: none;
}

.show-on-hover:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-on-hover">
  <a>Hover over me!</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work but I want to place links in a another area, so this method would work since all content needs to be inside one div

Comment: @IniyaAssaf Does the first method work using your original HTML structure? It might help to edit your question and show that other area designed for links; that might provide more context for what you're aiming to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code, it a navigation box that I'm trying to make a menu appear on the right side when visitor hover over menu item "Desserts"